What is the best way to generate permutations of columns
I have a scala DF that looks like this:
+---+-----+----+----+----+
|ID |info |col1|col2|col3|
+---+-----+----+----+----+
|id1|info1|a1  |a2  |a3  |
|id2|info2|a1  |a3  |a4  |
+---+-----+----+----+----+

I want to generate all permutations of (col1, col2, col3) while keeping data from columns "ID" and "info" the same.
The output would look like this:
+---+-----+----+----+----+
|ID |info |col1|col2|col3|
+---+-----+----+----+----+
|id1|info1|a1  |a2  |a3  |
|id1|info1|a1  |a3  |a2  |
|id1|info1|a2  |a1  |a3  |
|id1|info1|a2  |a3  |a1  |
|id1|info1|a3  |a1  |a2  |
|id1|info1|a3  |a2  |a1  |
|id2|info2|a1  |a3  |a4  |
|id2|info2|a1  |a4  |a3  |
|id2|info2|a3  |a1  |a4  |
|id2|info2|a3  |a4  |a1  |
|id2|info2|a4  |a1  |a3  |
|id2|info2|a4  |a3  |a1  |
+---+-----+----+----+----+


My current thought process for the solution is as follows, but I am curious if there is a better way:

Create a new column with (col1, col2, col3) merged into an array
Generate array permutations using scala's permutations method
Explode the new column
Map each index of the array in exploded column to new col1, col2, and col3


I guess you could skip the 1 and 3 by using flatMap: for each row of 1st dataset, generate N news rows.

Have you found an answer to your question?

You could use the Seq.permutations function wrapped within a UDF as follows:
// generating data
val df = Seq(
    ("id1", "info1", "a1", "a2", "a3"),
    ("id2", "info2", "a1", "a3", "a4")
).toDF("ID", "info", "col1", "col2", "col3")
df
    .select('ID, 'info, explode(permutations(array('col1, 'col2, 'col3))) as "cols")
    .select('ID, 'info, 'cols(0) as "col1", 'cols(1) as "col2", 'cols(2) as "col3")
    .show

+---+-----+----+----+----+
| ID| info|col1|col2|col3|
+---+-----+----+----+----+
|id1|info1|  a1|  a2|  a3|
|id1|info1|  a1|  a3|  a2|
|id1|info1|  a2|  a1|  a3|
|id1|info1|  a2|  a3|  a1|
|id1|info1|  a3|  a1|  a2|
|id1|info1|  a3|  a2|  a1|
|id2|info2|  a1|  a3|  a4|
|id2|info2|  a1|  a4|  a3|
|id2|info2|  a3|  a1|  a4|
|id2|info2|  a3|  a4|  a1|
|id2|info2|  a4|  a1|  a3|
|id2|info2|  a4|  a3|  a1|
+---+-----+----+----+----+

